# How to create test case in azure devops using rest api in python

Tags: python-3.x, azure-devops-rest-api

Can anyone please share the details how to create a test case in azure devops using rest api, preferably in python code. I couldn't find a direct API in azure devops but they shared an API for work item. But I don't have an idea how the body should be while creating a test case. Please suggest.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/wit/work%20items/create?view=azure-devops-rest-6.1

Comment: Regarding the body of the work item while creating test case is not mentioned anywhere. I have seen this example code for get projects but it would be great if anyone share a sample code to create a work item as test case with the exact body format. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

> How to create test case in azure devops using rest api in python

The test case is also a work item. That is the reason why they shared an API for work item for you.

When you create a workitem with TestCase type:

[image]

Then we could find it display on the test case tab:

[image]

So, we could use the REST API [Create a work item](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/integrate/previous-apis/wit/work-items?view=azure-devops-2020#create-a-work-item) to create a workitem with Testcase type to create the test case:

```
PATCH https://{instance}/DefaultCollection/{project}/_apis/wit/workitems/${workItemTypeName}?api-version={version}
```

On the other hand, we could check the REST API about the [Test cases](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/integrate/previous-apis/test/cases?view=azure-devops-2020&viewFallbackFrom=azure-devops), there are Get a test case, Delete a test case but no create the test case API directly.

To create a workitem in python, you could refer this [official Azure DevOps Python API](https://github.com/microsoft/azure-devops-python-api) doc.

> It contains Python APIs for interacting with and managing Azure
> DevOps. These APIs power the Azure DevOps Extension for Azure CLI. To
> learn more about the Azure DevOps Extension for Azure CLI, visit the
> Microsoft/azure-devops-cli-extension repo.

Here is some example code for [creating work item in python](https://github.com/Azure/azure-devops-cli-extension/blob/768aff8971aad2e194fa26d796d47b3a67292b4e/azure-devops/azext_devops/dev/boards/work_item.py#L24).

You could check [this thread](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/481550/create-a-test-case-and-along-with-test-steps-using.html) for some more details.

Comment: I have seen many post which mentions the same that I can create a test case by using work item. But I didnt find any post where it actually mentions what should be the data input to the rest api while creating a test case using create work item api. Can somebody please help me as Im getting error by giving the data shared in microsoft doc for azure rest api.